# Baseboard register/vent sizing

Tags: register

We recently purchased an older home (1943) I need to replace the old baseboard register. They had a 24inch baseboard register and upon taking it off and measuring the vent opening is only 15inches. Do i need to replace with a 15inch baseboard register or is replacing with a 24in fine? The only problem with buying a 15 inch is I will have spots with no trim and won't be able to match the existing trim.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an oversized register on the vent was probably done for aesthetic purposes.  It should have no impact on the heating system.  If the register were to reduce flow it would be a concern but going from smaller opening to larger register won't do a thing to heat distribution.

Comment: A picture of the register would be great. That said, there were baseboard registers that were made in many very large sizes. I have only seen them once or twice, so a picture would help identify them.